# How check text is 1 byte or 2 byte?

Tags: vb.net

I have a sentence:
ex:

```
 String value="123抽出";
```

`123` is text `1 byte`;

`抽出` is text `2 byte`;

How check text is `1 byte` or `2 byte`?

Comment: All strings are in Unicode = 2 bytes.

Comment: What is your question edit hoping to achieve? Are you still doubting that .net encodes strings using UTF-16?

Answer (score 4):

Exact answer (C# code):

```
 char c = value[0];
 bool haveHighByteNonEmpty =  (c > 256);
```

Note that if you want "ASCII" than range is actually different - 0-127, if you want length in some other encoding like UTF8 you should use corresponding methods of [Encodings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class/instances.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are unicode and hence are 2 bytes. You may try something like this:

```
Dim u As System.Text.UnicodeEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
Dim a As System.Text.ASCIIEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII

MsgBox(u.GetByteCount("123"))
MsgBox(s.GetByteCount("123"))
```

Also check [How to check the Single Bytes and Double Bytes character ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f3630fd-cbaf-4224-a214-12d6676f3eb8/how-to-check-the-single-bytes-and-double-bytes-character-?forum=vbgeneral)